# Where Clause Statement Repeating Data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database that has been populated with some data using create and insert into statements. I have written a SELECT statement that has a WHERE clause. The problem that I am encountering is that when I run the statement I have found that some of the data is repeating for what reason I don't understand.

This the statement that I am trying to run.

```
    SELECT Customer_Contact, Customer.CustomerID, Ord.OrderID,ItemOrdered.BeltLength,ItemOrdered.Colour,
ItemOrdered.Quantity,Design.DesignStyle 
    FROM Customer, Ord, ItemOrdered,Design
    WHERE Customer.CustomerID = Ord.CustomerID
    and Customer.Customer_Contact = 'John Daley' 
and Design.DesignStyle ='Flat-Engraved';
```

The following link displays all the relevant code, that I have used for to create the above statement. [Database Code][1]

I have laid it out in the following format:

```
CREATE STATEMENT 
INSERT INTO STATEMENT
```

Expanded Where clause and looks like the following:

```
SELECT Customer_Contact, Customer.CustomerID, Ord.OrderID,ItemOrdered.BeltLength,ItemOrdered.Colour,
ItemOrdered.Quantity,Design.DesignStyle 
FROM Customer, Ord, ItemOrdered,Design
WHERE Customer.CustomerID = Ord.CustomerID and 
ItemOrdered.OrderID = Ord.OrderID
and Customer.Customer_Contact = 'John Daley' and 
Design.DesignStyle ='Flat-Engraved';
```

This works, however when I run the statement it brings up 3 records that are exactly the same.

```
SELECT Customer.Customer_Contact, 
       Customer.CustomerID, 
       Ord.OrderID,
       ItemOrdered.BeltLength,
       ItemOrdered.Colour,
       ItemOrdered.Quantity,
       Design.DesignStyle
  FROM Customer,
       Ord, 
       ItemOrdered,
       BeltID
       Design
 WHERE Customer.CustomerID       = Ord.CustomerID
   AND Ord.OrderID               = ItemOrdered.OrderID
   AND Customer.Customer_Contact = 'John Daley' 
   AND Design.DesignStyle        ='Flat-Engraved'
   AND BeltID.DesignID           = Design.DesignID;
```

The above statement is giving me an invalid identifier error, which I seem to not understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to select something from the Design and ItemOrdered tables, but you are not including them in your join.

You probably need to expand your where-clause (with and-statements), where you link the ItemOrdered and Design tables to your Customer or Customer_Contract tables.

Comment: I expanded my where clause so it looks like the above. I have edited the fields.

Comment: user532339: What about the Design table that is joined? The key doesn't exist as a foreign key in any other table.

Comment: The design table is joined. It is joined to the BeltID the following link shows how they are joined. http://pastebin.com/rrCr9M46

Answer (score 3):

Your WHERE clause seems rather lax. The Customer to Ord join seems pretty strong but ItemOrdered doesn't even appear in the WHERE clause which is probably causing a [Cartesian Join](http://www.fluffycat.com/SQL/Cartesian-Joins/).

Comment: Would you suggest that include the ItemOrdered into the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your create statements here is how I would create most of the Joins. The Design table however doesn't seem to be referenced by any of the other tables so one would need more information to complete the query

```
SELECT 
    Customer_Contact, 
    Customer.CustomerID, 
    Ord.OrderID,
    ItemOrdered.BeltLength,
    ItemOrdered.Colour,
    ItemOrdered.Quantity --,
--Design.DesignStyle 
    FROM 
        Customer, 
        INNER JOIN Ord
        ON Customer.CustomerID = Ord.CustomerID 
        INNER JOIN ItemOrdered 
        ON ord.OrderID = ItemOrderd.OrderID
        -- INNER JOIN design
    WHERE 
          Customer.Customer_Contact = 'John Daley' 


--and Design.DesignStyle ='Flat-Engraved';
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you are joining N tables together, you want to provide at least N-1 join conditions.  Since you are joining 4 tables, you would normally need at least 3 join conditions.  If the intention is for the DesignStyle column to be unique (that's unclear from the DDL you linked to) then this should work.

```
SELECT Customer.Customer_Contact, 
       Customer.CustomerID, 
       Ord.OrderID,
       ItemOrdered.BeltLength,
       ItemOrdered.Colour,
       ItemOrdered.Quantity,
       Design.DesignStyle 
  FROM Customer,
       Ord, 
       ItemOrdered,
       Design
 WHERE Customer.CustomerID       = Ord.CustomerID
   AND Ord.OrderID               = ItemOrdered.OrderID
   AND Customer.Customer_Contact = 'John Daley' 
   AND Design.DesignStyle        ='Flat-Engraved';
```

Normally, however, your data model would have some sort of Item table that had a foreign key to the Design table and the ItemOrdered table would be an intersection between the Item and Order tables.  That would make the joins far more sensible.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but my join and your join do the same thing. I am still encountering this problem. This following link displays what the problem that is keeps occurring http://imgur.com/UjrbC

Comment: Any chance you could edit your question to include the information you're linking to?  I can't access that URL from behind my firewall.

Comment: I have a DesignID that is a foreign key in a BeltID table, I have the following statement structured. But gives ORA-00904: "BELTID"."DESIGNID": invalid identifier. How exactly is it invalid when I have identified it in the my statement?

Comment: I took your understanding of things and adapted it. However I seem to be getting three duplicate records of the same thing.